# Not a group by expression in my oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following sql query that I m not able to process since this afternoon.

I have seen lot of threads about this issue but I m not getting it right, I believe that I m miss understanding this one topic that is shaming my day.

```
SELECT
    cor.c_order_id, cor.totallines,cor.documentno,cbp.name
FROM
    c_orderline   col
    LEFT JOIN c_order       cor ON cor.c_order_id = col.c_order_id
    LEFT join c_bpartner    cbp on cbp.c_bpartner_id = cor.c_bpartner_id
WHERE
    cor.issotrx = 'Y'
    and cor.docstatus not in ('DR','IP')
    AND cor.salesrep_id = 1037317
    and col.qtyordered <> 0
    and cor.dateordered between SYSDATE - 30  and SYSDATE + 30
    AND col.c_orderline_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            cil.c_orderline_id
        FROM
            c_invoiceline cil
        WHERE
            cil.c_orderline_id IS NOT NULL
    )
    group by cor.c_order_id, cor.documentno
    order by cor.c_order_id, cor.documentno
```

What I m doing wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group by is used for aggregate functions like sum(), max(), min() etc. What value are you calculating in groups?

remove the group by and your query looks good besides that

Comment: ok using distinct is not a king of grouping by ?? I want to have the same effect without using this key word

Comment: You can think of it that way, but all four columns in your select would need to have been in the group by for it to have worked.

Answer (score 3):

A simplified example, based on Scott's EMP table.

This is what you did:

```
SQL> select deptno, job
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;
select deptno, job
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

As you can see, Oracle marked the culprit - the `JOB` column.

Therefore, if you want to use a `GROUP BY` clause (which is correct, but - you'd get the same result using `DISTINCT`; these two should not be used together. `GROUP BY` is usually used with aggregates such as `min`, `max`, `avg` and such), then put all columns into the `GROUP BY`:

```
SQL> select deptno, job
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        20 CLERK
        30 SALESMAN
        20 MANAGER
        30 CLERK
        10 PRESIDENT
        30 MANAGER
        10 CLERK
        10 MANAGER
        20 ANALYST

9 rows selected.
```

Or, as I said - using `DISTINCT`:

```
SQL> select distinct deptno, job
  2  from emp;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        20 CLERK
        30 SALESMAN
        20 MANAGER
        30 CLERK
        10 PRESIDENT
        30 MANAGER
        10 CLERK
        10 MANAGER
        20 ANALYST

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

To correct the error this query is producing you need to

```
group by cor.c_order_id, cor.totallines,cor.documentno,cbp.name
```

Group by all the columns that are in the select statement and are not part of aggregate function.
What else is a problem?
[Here is the DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=930fbbcdafbaad143550c7d4ed77dbd5)

In this demo you will see that the query works(with the correction I have suggested), but as I asked, what else is a problem to you. Do elaborate so we can help. Cheers!

Comment: Im not using an agregation and this missleaded me, to believe that when there is no agregation there is no need to specify all columns , however I dont understand whythey say all colums are needed in case of agregation, is the absence of agregation concidered ademon one and that s whywe need to specify ? what really is happening deeply on this ... that what  i m not getting right

Comment: I am not sure if this will explain something to you but let's try: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=513df12770668d75eea455aa1c466fed

Comment: With this link that I have sent you in my previous comment I suggest to take some time and play with different examples and you will soon understand the logic behind the group by clause and why you need to specify all the columns to get some result(regardless to if there are aggregate functions or not.) Also take look at the great answer from @Littlefoot